# Get blog name from ID in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm making the cards for my blogposts in shopify and am encountering a problem.

I want to put in the blog name in the card, but within the article component I only get an ID (under 'blog_id').

Thing is, I can't seem to find a way by which you can take an ID to query shopify to get the blog name. The only thing I can seem to find in the docs is querying an article via its URL. https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#articles

So is there a way to query shopify with a blog id to get the information on that blog, and at least the title?

Answer (score 0):

When you loop your `blog.articles` you have access to the `blog` object.

If your card is a snippet, you can pass the `blog` object, so you will have access to it on the snippet.

```
{% for article in blog.articles %}
   <div class="swiper-slide">
      {% render 'card-article',
         blog: blog,
         article: article,
      %}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you do not need the whole `blog` object, you can pass only the name.

About `article` templates, you have access to `blog` object.

Another hacky solution is to extract the blog name from the `article.handle`. It will look something like this:

```
{% assign blog_name = article.handle | split: '/' | first %}

<h6 class="article__blog">{{ blog_name | capitalize }}</h6>
```